# Can I assign a form to a variable?

Tags: javascript, forms, variables

So if I have a form called myForm and a field called myField, I know I can access that field by using:

```
document.myForm.myField.value
```

Is there a way to assign the form itself to a variable like:

```
var f = document.myForm
```

so that I can access the fields by just using:
`f.myField.value` in order to save myself some typing?

I tried it and it didn't work so I don't know if it's not possible or if I'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: No reason you shouldn't be able to.  What did you try?  Can you post what didn't work?

Comment: My wild guess is that you did this in a script in `<head>` and tried to save the form variable before it exists in the document. Or maybe you just saved it into a local scope other than the one you're using it in. You'll need to post a more complete example of what you tried.

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I was working in the header area setting up all my functions and things.  Didn't think about that.  Doh!

Answer (score 4):

[Yes.](http://jsbin.com/efEsolA/1/edit)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="example">
    <input name="field" value="default value">
  </form>
  <script>
    var frm = document.forms.example;
    alert(frm.elements.field.value);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah of course you can do it! Just add a variable like `var act_form = document.forms["myform"]; //make use of it 
var action =act_form.action, method = act_form.method;
alert(method);`

and in the form contains
`<form name="myform" method="post" action="example.com"></form>`